# How to limit the height of the dropdown list of a select component from chakra ui?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I have a form with a field for countries and one for states. The country one is an autocomplete input that when you pick a country, fills a list of states from that country and passes the list to a select component from chakra ui. The thing is the list is so long it goues beyond the limits of the parent component and even as far down as outside the screen. Is there a prop or way to limit the height of the dropdown list?
Here is the code:

```
 <Flex width="100%" direction="column" gap="8px">
      <CustomText fontWeight={500} fontSize={fontSize}>
        {label}
      </CustomText>
      <Select
        bg={Colors.background_white}
        variant="outline"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={handleChoose}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        listStylePos={"inside"}
        ref={ref}
        disabled={disabled}
        name={name}
        sx={{
          listStyle: {
            height: "3rem",
            maxHeight: "4rem",
            overflow: "auto",
          },
        }}
        h="3rem"
        maxH={"4rem"}
        /*         maxHeight={100} */
        overflow={"auto"}
        border={hasBorder ? `1px solid ${Colors.border_input}` : "none"}
        isDisabled={options?.length === 0 || !options}
        _focus={{
          border: `1px solid ${Colors.primary_main}`,
          color: Colors.text_primary,
        }}
        _focusVisible={{
          border: `1px solid ${Colors.primary_main}`,
          color: Colors.text_primary,
        }}
        _hover={{
          border: `1px solid ${Colors.primary_main}`,
          color: Colors.text_primary,
        }}
        value={value}
      >
        {options?.map((option) => (
          <option key={option.label + option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </option>
        ))}
      </Select>
      <InputErrorMessage message={error?.message} />
    </Flex>
```

I've tried using maxHeight but that affects the box of the 'input' and not the list itself.